# Have multiple joins populate single column in query.

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to create a report query that joins multiple tables.  These tables have a shared field (method) between them.  I have a table with two foreign key columns.

**Main Table**

```
Book_id fooid barid
1        1      null
2        null      1
3        4      null
```

**Foo Table**

```
foo_id method 
1        this      
4        that
```

**Bar Table**

```
bar_id method 
1        where
2        why
```

**Query Result**

```
Book_id method 
1        this
2        where
3        that
```

I realize I could use an if null to get the desired results.  Is this the best way?  If I end up joining 3 or 4 tables (and adding foreign key columns to main table) the query seems like it would become hard to manage.

Thanks,
M

Comment: What should the result be if both `fooid` and `barid` are filled in?

Comment: ifnull or equivalent is the way to go. 4 tables is a tiny query still, so no worries about that yet :)

Comment: COALESCE seems simpler for scalability

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UNION`

```
SELECT m.book_id, f.method
FROM Foo AS f
JOIN Main AS m ON f.foo_id = m.fooid
UNION
SELECT m.book_id, b.method
FROM Bar as b
JOIN Main AS m ON b.bar_id = m.barid
```

If you have more tables, just add more subqueries to the union.

You could also use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to find the non-null match.

```
SELECT m.book_id, COALESCE(f.method, b.method) AS method
FROM Main as m
LEFT JOIN Foo AS f ON f.foo_id = m.fooid
LEFT JOIN Bar AS b ON b.bar_id = m.barid
```

With more tables, add more `LEFT JOIN` rows and add the appropriate fields to the `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select book_id
     , coalesce(foo.method, bar.method, 'value if null') as method
-- -------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- What should go here if both fooid and barid are null?
from main
     left join foo on main.book_id = foo.foo_id
     left join bar on main.book_id = bar.bar_id
```